# The 'flet build' process becomes unresponsive during the extraction of the Python distribution

Tags: python, flet

I am trying to create an APK file of my app, using `flet build apk`.

To get the logs I used `flet build apk --verbose -vv`.

```bash
Packaging Python app...
Run subprocess: ['E:\\Flutter\\flutter\\bin\\dart.BAT', 'run', 'serious_python:main', 'package',
'C:\\Users\\minik\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\AndroidApp', '--mobile', '--platform', 'mobile', '--dep-mappings',
'flet=flet-embed', '--req-deps', 'flet-embed', '--exclude', 'build', '--verbose']
Building package executable... (1.7s)
Built serious_python:main.
Running package command
Creating asset directory: C:\Users\minik\AppData\Local\Temp\flet_flutter_build_iVWwjetaxF\app
Copying Python app from C:\Users\minik\OneDrive\Desktop\AndroidApp to C:\Users\minik\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_tempf4660737
Configured mobile platform with sitecustomize.py at C:\Users\minik\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_sitecustomizef84b41c4\sitecustomize.py
Installing dependencies [flet-embed, flet_easy, alertapi==0.0.7] with pip command to C:\Users\minik\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_tempf4660737\__pypackages__
Extracting Python distributive from C:\Users\minik\AppData\Local\Temp\cpython-3.11.6+20231002-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc-shared-install_only.tar.gz to C:\Users\minik\AppData\Local\Temp\hostpython3.11_f119ba11
VERBOSE: C:\Users\minik\AppData\Local\Temp\hostpython3.11_f119ba11\python\python.exe -m pip install --isolated --upgrade --target C:\Users\minik\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_tempf4660737\__pypackages__ flet-embed flet_easy alertapi==0.0.7
VERBOSE: Collecting flet-embed
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for flet-embed from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7e/21/ccff70db26983b53932a394443ef631334dbd9f69bf145613438aa4b7193/flet_embed-0.20.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached flet_embed-0.20.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.1 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting flet_easy
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for flet_easy from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/16/265384386f93180b2cb11e731f16722d7ef8e676f9790399641451c08bea/flet_easy-0.1.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached flet_easy-0.1.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.8 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting alertapi==0.0.7
VERBOSE: Using cached alertapi-0.0.7-py3-none-any.whl
VERBOSE: Collecting attrs==21.4.0 (from alertapi==0.0.7)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for attrs==21.4.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/be/be/7abce643bfdf8ca01c48afa2ddf8308c2308b0c3b239a44e57d020afa0ef/attrs-21.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached attrs-21.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.8 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting aiohttp==3.8.4 (from alertapi==0.0.7)
VERBOSE: Using cached aiohttp-3.8.4.tar.gz (7.3 MB)
VERBOSE: Installing build dependencies: started
VERBOSE: Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
VERBOSE: Getting requirements to build wheel: started
VERBOSE: Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
VERBOSE: Installing backend dependencies: started
VERBOSE: Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
VERBOSE: Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
VERBOSE: Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
VERBOSE: Collecting aiohttp-sse-client==0.2.1 (from alertapi==0.0.7)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for aiohttp-sse-client==0.2.1 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/25/c9/ad514e70a549db22e118f0366c0bb38c5a90cb407978cb6c3d1482760889/aiohttp_sse_client-0.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached aiohttp_sse_client-0.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.7 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting charset-normalizer<4.0,>=2.0 (from aiohttp==3.8.4->alertapi==0.0.7)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for charset-normalizer<4.0,>=2.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/28/76/e6222113b83e3622caa4bb41032d0b1bf785250607392e1b778aca0b8a7d/charset_normalizer-3.3.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached charset_normalizer-3.3.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (33 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting multidict<7.0,>=4.5 (from aiohttp==3.8.4->alertapi==0.0.7)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for multidict<7.0,>=4.5 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fa/a2/17e1e23c6be0a916219c5292f509360c345b5fa6beeb50d743203c27532c/multidict-6.0.5-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached multidict-6.0.5-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.2 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting async-timeout<5.0,>=4.0.0a3 (from aiohttp==3.8.4->alertapi==0.0.7)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for async-timeout<5.0,>=4.0.0a3 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a7/fa/e01228c2938de91d47b307831c62ab9e4001e747789d0b05baf779a6488c/async_timeout-4.0.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached async_timeout-4.0.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.2 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting yarl<2.0,>=1.0 (from aiohttp==3.8.4->alertapi==0.0.7)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for yarl<2.0,>=1.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4d/05/4d79198ae568a92159de0f89e710a8d19e3fa267b719a236582eee921f4a/yarl-1.9.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached yarl-1.9.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (31 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting frozenlist>=1.1.1 (from aiohttp==3.8.4->alertapi==0.0.7)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for frozenlist>=1.1.1 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/83/10/466fe96dae1bff622021ee687f68e5524d6392b0a2f80d05001cd3a451ba/frozenlist-1.4.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached frozenlist-1.4.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (12 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting aiosignal>=1.1.2 (from aiohttp==3.8.4->alertapi==0.0.7)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for aiosignal>=1.1.2 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/76/ac/a7305707cb852b7e16ff80eaf5692309bde30e2b1100a1fcacdc8f731d97/aiosignal-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached aiosignal-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.0 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting flet-runtime==0.20.2 (from flet-embed)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for flet-runtime==0.20.2 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/31/ef/f740ad601da8e9dcaacaec5bb47a2443baee4904b4b1156fe50c4355ea70/flet_runtime-0.20.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached flet_runtime-0.20.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.2 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting flet-core==0.20.2 (from flet-runtime==0.20.2->flet-embed)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for flet-core==0.20.2 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/89/29/75346964a474c6838281818cb2aee83c9c6b263d5901fd141a9b199df0d3/flet_core-0.20.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached flet_core-0.20.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.1 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting httpx<0.25.0,>=0.24.1 (from flet-runtime==0.20.2->flet-embed)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for httpx<0.25.0,>=0.24.1 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/91/e41f64f03d2a13aee7e8c819d82ee3aa7cdc484d18c0ae859742597d5aa0/httpx-0.24.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached httpx-0.24.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.4 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting oauthlib<4.0.0,>=3.2.2 (from flet-runtime==0.20.2->flet-embed)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for oauthlib<4.0.0,>=3.2.2 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7e/80/cab10959dc1faead58dc8384a781dfbf93cb4d33d50988f7a69f1b7c9bbe/oauthlib-3.2.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached oauthlib-3.2.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.5 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting repath<0.10.0,>=0.9.0 (from flet-core==0.20.2->flet-runtime==0.20.2->flet-embed)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for repath<0.10.0,>=0.9.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/87/ed/92e9b8a3ffc562f21df14ef2538f54e911df29730e1f0d79130a4edc86e7/repath-0.9.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached repath-0.9.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (899 bytes)
VERBOSE: Collecting flet (from flet_easy)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for flet from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c8/d6/dc1913e8a39e0beb79789a84812d4dcbe834c3932f30482efdce16937ce0/flet-0.20.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached flet-0.20.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.4 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting parse (from flet_easy)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for parse from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ce/f0/30fe1494f1910ad3ea40639b13ac48cdb16a8600e8861cbfc2c560661ddf/parse-1.20.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached parse-1.20.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (22 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting cookiecutter<3.0.0,>=2.4.0 (from flet->flet_easy)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for cookiecutter<3.0.0,>=2.4.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b6/d9/0137658a353168ffa9d0fc14b812d3834772040858ddd1cb6eeaf09f7a44/cookiecutter-2.6.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached cookiecutter-2.6.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.3 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting packaging<24.0,>=23.1 (from flet->flet_easy)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for packaging<24.0,>=23.1 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/1a/610693ac4ee14fcdf2d9bf3c493370e4f2ef7ae2e19217d7a237ff42367d/packaging-23.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached packaging-23.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.2 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting qrcode<8.0.0,>=7.4.2 (from flet->flet_easy)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for qrcode<8.0.0,>=7.4.2 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/24/79/aaf0c1c7214f2632badb2771d770b1500d3d7cbdf2590ae62e721ec50584/qrcode-7.4.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached qrcode-7.4.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (17 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting watchdog<4.0.0,>=3.0.0 (from flet->flet_easy)
VERBOSE: Using cached watchdog-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
VERBOSE: Collecting websocket-client<2.0.0,>=1.5.2 (from flet->flet_easy)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for websocket-client<2.0.0,>=1.5.2 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1e/70/1e88138a9afbed1d37093b85f0bebc3011623c4f47c166431599fe9d6c93/websocket_client-1.7.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached websocket_client-1.7.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.9 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting websockets<12.0.0,>=11.0.3 (from flet->flet_easy)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for websockets<12.0.0,>=11.0.3 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/47/96/9d5749106ff57629b54360664ae7eb9afd8302fad1680ead385383e33746/websockets-11.0.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached websockets-11.0.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.6 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting binaryornot>=0.4.4 (from cookiecutter<3.0.0,>=2.4.0->flet->flet_easy)
VERBOSE: Using cached binaryornot-0.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.0 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting Jinja2<4.0.0,>=2.7 (from cookiecutter<3.0.0,>=2.4.0->flet->flet_easy)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for Jinja2<4.0.0,>=2.7 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/30/6d/6de6be2d02603ab56e72997708809e8a5b0fbfee080735109b40a3564843/Jinja2-3.1.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached Jinja2-3.1.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.3 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting click<9.0.0,>=7.0 (from cookiecutter<3.0.0,>=2.4.0->flet->flet_easy)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for click<9.0.0,>=7.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/2e/d53fa4befbf2cfa713304affc7ca780ce4fc1fd8710527771b58311a3229/click-8.1.7-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached click-8.1.7-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting pyyaml>=5.3.1 (from cookiecutter<3.0.0,>=2.4.0->flet->flet_easy)
VERBOSE: Using cached PyYAML-6.0.1.tar.gz (125 kB)
VERBOSE: Installing build dependencies: started
VERBOSE: Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
VERBOSE: Getting requirements to build wheel: started
VERBOSE: Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
VERBOSE: Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
VERBOSE: Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
VERBOSE: Collecting python-slugify>=4.0.0 (from cookiecutter<3.0.0,>=2.4.0->flet->flet_easy)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for python-slugify>=4.0.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a4/62/02da182e544a51a5c3ccf4b03ab79df279f9c60c5e82d5e8bec7ca26ac11/python_slugify-8.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached python_slugify-8.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.5 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting requests>=2.23.0 (from cookiecutter<3.0.0,>=2.4.0->flet->flet_easy)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for requests>=2.23.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/70/8e/0e2d847013cb52cd35b38c009bb167a1a26b2ce6cd6965bf26b47bc0bf44/requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.6 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting arrow (from cookiecutter<3.0.0,>=2.4.0->flet->flet_easy)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for arrow from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f8/ed/e97229a566617f2ae958a6b13e7cc0f585470eac730a73e9e82c32a3cdd2/arrow-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached arrow-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.5 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting rich (from cookiecutter<3.0.0,>=2.4.0->flet->flet_easy)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for rich from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/87/67/a37f6214d0e9fe57f6ae54b2956d550ca8365857f42a1ce0392bb21d9410/rich-13.7.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached rich-13.7.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (18 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting certifi (from httpx<0.25.0,>=0.24.1->flet-runtime==0.20.2->flet-embed)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for certifi from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ba/06/a07f096c664aeb9f01624f858c3add0a4e913d6c96257acb4fce61e7de14/certifi-2024.2.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached certifi-2024.2.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting httpcore<0.18.0,>=0.15.0 (from httpx<0.25.0,>=0.24.1->flet-runtime==0.20.2->flet-embed)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for httpcore<0.18.0,>=0.15.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/94/2c/2bde7ff8dd2064395555220cbf7cba79991172bf5315a07eb3ac7688d9f1/httpcore-0.17.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached httpcore-0.17.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (18 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting idna (from httpx<0.25.0,>=0.24.1->flet-runtime==0.20.2->flet-embed)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for idna from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/e7/a82b05cf63a603df6e68d59ae6a68bf5064484a0718ea5033660af4b54a9/idna-3.6-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached idna-3.6-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.9 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting sniffio (from httpx<0.25.0,>=0.24.1->flet-runtime==0.20.2->flet-embed)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for sniffio from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/44/75a9c9421471a6c4805dbf2356f7c181a29c1879239abab1ea2cc8f38b40/sniffio-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached sniffio-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.9 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting typing-extensions (from qrcode<8.0.0,>=7.4.2->flet->flet_easy)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for typing-extensions from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f9/de/dc04a3ea60b22624b51c703a84bbe0184abcd1d0b9bc8074b5d6b7ab90bb/typing_extensions-4.10.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached typing_extensions-4.10.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting pypng (from qrcode<8.0.0,>=7.4.2->flet->flet_easy)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for pypng from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3e/b9/3766cc361d93edb2ce81e2e1f87dd98f314d7d513877a342d31b30741680/pypng-0.20220715.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached pypng-0.20220715.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (13 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting chardet>=3.0.2 (from binaryornot>=0.4.4->cookiecutter<3.0.0,>=2.4.0->flet->flet_easy)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for chardet>=3.0.2 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/38/6f/f5fbc992a329ee4e0f288c1fe0e2ad9485ed064cac731ed2fe47dcc38cbf/chardet-5.2.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached chardet-5.2.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.4 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting h11<0.15,>=0.13 (from httpcore<0.18.0,>=0.15.0->httpx<0.25.0,>=0.24.1->flet-runtime==0.20.2->flet-embed)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for h11<0.15,>=0.13 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/95/04/ff642e65ad6b90db43e668d70ffb6736436c7ce41fcc549f4e9472234127/h11-0.14.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached h11-0.14.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.2 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting anyio<5.0,>=3.0 (from httpcore<0.18.0,>=0.15.0->httpx<0.25.0,>=0.24.1->flet-runtime==0.20.2->flet-embed)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for anyio<5.0,>=3.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/fd/2f20c40b45e4fb4324834aea24bd4afdf1143390242c0b33774da0e2e34f/anyio-4.3.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached anyio-4.3.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.6 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting MarkupSafe>=2.0 (from Jinja2<4.0.0,>=2.7->cookiecutter<3.0.0,>=2.4.0->flet->flet_easy)
VERBOSE: Using cached MarkupSafe-2.1.5-py3-none-any.whl
VERBOSE: Collecting text-unidecode>=1.3 (from python-slugify>=4.0.0->cookiecutter<3.0.0,>=2.4.0->flet->flet_easy)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for text-unidecode>=1.3 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a6/a5/c0b6468d3824fe3fde30dbb5e1f687b291608f9473681bbf7dabbf5a87d7/text_unidecode-1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached text_unidecode-1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.4 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting six>=1.9.0 (from repath<0.10.0,>=0.9.0->flet-core==0.20.2->flet-runtime==0.20.2->flet-embed)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for six>=1.9.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d9/5a/e7c31adbe875f2abbb91bd84cf2dc52d792b5a01506781dbcf25c91daf11/six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.8 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 (from requests>=2.23.0->cookiecutter<3.0.0,>=2.4.0->flet->flet_easy)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a2/73/a68704750a7679d0b6d3ad7aa8d4da8e14e151ae82e6fee774e6e0d05ec8/urllib3-2.2.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached urllib3-2.2.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.4 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting python-dateutil>=2.7.0 (from arrow->cookiecutter<3.0.0,>=2.4.0->flet->flet_easy)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for python-dateutil>=2.7.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/57/56b9bcc3c9c6a792fcbaf139543cee77261f3651ca9da0c93f5c1221264b/python_dateutil-2.9.0.post0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached python_dateutil-2.9.0.post0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.4 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting types-python-dateutil>=2.8.10 (from arrow->cookiecutter<3.0.0,>=2.4.0->flet->flet_easy)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for types-python-dateutil>=2.8.10 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/28/50/8ed67814241e2684369f4b8b881c7d31a0816e76c8690ea8518017a35b7e/types_python_dateutil-2.8.19.20240106-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached types_python_dateutil-2.8.19.20240106-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.8 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting markdown-it-py>=2.2.0 (from rich->cookiecutter<3.0.0,>=2.4.0->flet->flet_easy)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for markdown-it-py>=2.2.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/42/d7/1ec15b46af6af88f19b8e5ffea08fa375d433c998b8a7639e76935c14f1f/markdown_it_py-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached markdown_it_py-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.9 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting pygments<3.0.0,>=2.13.0 (from rich->cookiecutter<3.0.0,>=2.4.0->flet->flet_easy)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for pygments<3.0.0,>=2.13.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/97/9c/372fef8377a6e340b1704768d20daaded98bf13282b5327beb2e2fe2c7ef/pygments-2.17.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached pygments-2.17.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.6 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting mdurl~=0.1 (from markdown-it-py>=2.2.0->rich->cookiecutter<3.0.0,>=2.4.0->flet->flet_easy)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for mdurl~=0.1 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b3/38/89ba8ad64ae25be8de66a6d463314cf1eb366222074cfda9ee839c56a4b4/mdurl-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached mdurl-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.6 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached aiohttp_sse_client-0.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.0 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached attrs-21.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (60 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached flet_embed-0.20.2-py3-none-any.whl (2.9 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached flet_runtime-0.20.2-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached flet_core-0.20.2-py3-none-any.whl (323 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached flet_easy-0.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached flet-0.20.2-py3-none-any.whl (2.6 MB)
VERBOSE: Using cached parse-1.20.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached aiosignal-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (7.6 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached async_timeout-4.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (5.7 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached charset_normalizer-3.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (48 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached cookiecutter-2.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached frozenlist-1.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached httpx-0.24.1-py3-none-any.whl (75 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached multidict-6.0.5-py3-none-any.whl (9.7 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached oauthlib-3.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (151 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached packaging-23.2-py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached qrcode-7.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (46 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached websocket_client-1.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached websockets-11.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (118 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached yarl-1.9.4-py3-none-any.whl (31 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached click-8.1.7-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached httpcore-0.17.3-py3-none-any.whl (74 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached sniffio-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached idna-3.6-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached Jinja2-3.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached python_slugify-8.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached repath-0.9.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.7 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached certifi-2024.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (163 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached arrow-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (66 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached pypng-0.20220715.0-py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached rich-13.7.1-py3-none-any.whl (240 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached typing_extensions-4.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached anyio-4.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (85 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached chardet-5.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (199 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached h11-0.14.0-py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached markdown_it_py-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (87 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached pygments-2.17.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
VERBOSE: Using cached python_dateutil-2.9.0.post0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (229 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached text_unidecode-1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (78 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached types_python_dateutil-2.8.19.20240106-py3-none-any.whl (9.7 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached urllib3-2.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (121 kB)
VERBOSE: Using cached mdurl-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (10.0 kB)
VERBOSE: Building wheels for collected packages: aiohttp, pyyaml
VERBOSE: Building wheel for aiohttp (pyproject.toml): started
VERBOSE: Building wheel for aiohttp (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
```

The process progresses successfully up to a certain point, my case `Packaging Python app...`, but then stops without any further action.
This are the `requirements.txt`

```
flet
flet_easy
alertapi==0.0.7
```

When I remove `alertapi` from the list of modules, everything is fine and I get the output of the apk file of my program